# Write log for curl on windows

Tags: curl, vbscript

I currently have a script that runs a curl function to fetch logs from another server, i am trying to debug some issues with this script and would like to enable logging for this curl function.

I have read that this can be achieved using the --trace file switch.

Can someone help me add this functionality to the below code?, the log must be unique for each curl call, perhaps using the date/time?

```
        '  Build the cURL command line.
    strcURL = chr(34) & strCodeBase & "curl" & chr(34) & " -s -f -o "
    strcURL = strcURL & chr(34) & strServerDir & strServer & "\gr" & strShortYear & strMonth & strDay & ".zip" & chr(34) & " "
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `--trace C:\logs\mytrace.log` to the argument list `" -s -f -o "`:

```
strcURL = chr(34) & strCodeBase & "curl" & chr(34) & " -s -f --trace C:\logs\mytrace.log -o "
```

The `-o` switch takes another argument (the location of the output file), which is why the `--trace` switch and its argument comes before it

Comment: Thanks Mathias! but i do not want this file overwritten every time this function is called, i would like to rotate or append it for each call, can you help me do this ?